# In SQL, how to format values so I have column1value.column2value

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and have some problems with formatting. In column1, I have categories living, food, transportation and in each category, I have subcategories. For example, food.lunch, food, grocery.

Now I want to have a new column called detailed expenses in which I want to display CATEGORY.SUBCATEGORY

for example, food.lunch

How can I achieve this? Any help?

Comment: What are you using? Oracle? SQLServer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure your table like this (not an OOP approach)

```
categories
-----------------------
id  name         parent
1   food         0
2   lunch        1
...
3   category     0
4   subcategory  3
```

Comment: and what is the next step after structuring the table like this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004543/recursive-child-parent-queries-in-t-sql) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187641/sql-cte-recursion-returning-parent-records)

Answer (score 0):

How about this idea: You can have a table Expenses that contains records to identify category and subcategory with an amount. Then you can total (SUM) the amounts by category or subcategory.

```
SELECT Category.Name,SubCategory.Name,SUM(Expense.Amount)
FROM Expense ex INNER JOIN Category cat on (ex.CategoryId = cat.Id)
INNER JOIN SubCategory subcat on (ex.SubCategoryId = subcat.Id)
GROUP BY cat.Name, subcat.Name,ex.Amount


CREATE TABLE Category(
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (Id),
)

CREATE TABLE SubCategory(
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CategoryId int,
Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES Category(Id))

CREATE TABLE Expense(
ID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CategoryId int,
SubCategoryId int,
Amount money
PRIMARY KEY (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES Category(Id)
FOREIGN KEY (SubCategoryId) REFERENCES SubCategory(Id))
```